# coordinate ring of a quasi-affine variety is equal to the coordinate ring of the ambient affine variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be an affine variety (an irreducible algebraic set) and $V$ An open subset of $X$.
Im trying to see why $A(X)=A(V)$.

In order to have that, i must show that $I(V)=I(X)$:

From $V\subset X$ we have $I(X)\subset I(V)$. For the reverse inclusion, I know that $V$ is dense in X (every open subset of an irreducible topological space is dense and irreductible) but do we have $I(V)=I(\overline{V})$ and why ??

Comment: Maybe try showing $f\in I(V) \Rightarrow f\in I(X)$ directly, i.e., if a polynomial vanishes on an open set, it vanishes on the whole of $X$.

Comment: You can show that $\overline{V}=\mathbf{V}(\mathbf{I}(V))$, then apply $\mathbf{I}$ to both sides.

Comment: The claim you're trying to prove is not true. If $X=\Bbb A^1$ and $V=\Bbb A^1\setminus 0$, then $A(X)=k[x]$ and $A(V)=k[x,x^{-1}]$.

Comment: what the meaning of $k[x,x^{-1}]$? here is where i saw that result : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LeJT94b_fYc minute 16

Comment: $x^{-1}$ is an element so that $xx^{-1}=1$. $k[x,x^{-1}]$ is the ring of polynomials in $x$ and $x^{-1}$. I am not watching some hour-and-a-half youtube video to answer your question, and I doubt many others will either. You need to put the relevant details in your question with an [edit].

Comment: You should add the definitions you are using from the video. I think that would help quite a bit.